# cant locate FILE/Find.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

As I said earlier, there is some directory called verilog which is HDL language used for hardware description. Inside this directory there are many sub-directories and .v files are available. So I need to search for a pattern called clk in all the files and the directory with the line number exactly where is the pattern located in each file and i need the count how many times clk has appeared. Now i could able to go through the directories and files but I could not get the line number of the file where the pattern has occured and the count(how many times the pattern has repeated) this is what I am looking for.Can you Plz help me on this?

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
#use strict;
#use FindBin;
#use lib File::Spec->catdir($FindBin::Bin,'Lib');
#use ExtUtils::Installed;

use File::Find;
use File::Slurp;
my $in_dir="/home/prodigydell3/verilog";
my @all_files;
my $pattern='test>clk(\n|\t|\s)</test';

find(sub {
push @all_files,$File::Find::name if(-f $File::Find::name);
},$in_dir);


my $count=0;
foreach my $file_(@all_files){

my @file_con=read_file($file_);
foreach my $con(@file_con){

my $match = "true" if ($con=~m/$pattern/igs);
$count++;
}
print "The pattern is found in $file_ and number of lines is $count \n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your script is trying to use [File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aFind), please change `FILE` to `File`. Perl is case sensitive.

BTW, posting a commentary to the error message would also be nice, not mentioning a question.

**Update:** After seeing your code, I can identify some problems: you probably define $count and $match at a wrong scope (hard to tell, because you never use $match). I tried to fix the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find;
use File::Slurp;
my $in_dir = '/home/prodigydell3/verilog';
my @all_files;
my $pattern = 'test>clk(\n|\t|\s)</test';

find(sub {
         push @all_files, $File::Find::name if (-f $File::Find::name);
     }, $in_dir);


foreach my $file_ (@all_files) {

    my $count = 0;
    my $match;
    my @file_con = read_file($file_);
    foreach my $con (@file_con) {

        $match = 1 if $con =~ m/$pattern/igs;
        $count++;
    }
    print "The pattern is found in $file_ and number of lines is $count \n" if $match;
}
```

Comment: Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.12.4 /usr/local/share/perl/5.12.4 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.12 /usr/share/perl/5.12 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at sample2.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at sample2.pl line 8.still same error.

Comment: @prashanth: No, it is a different error. This time, Perl cannot find `File::Slurp`, which is not a CORE module. How did you install it?

Comment: Now I am not able to remove both the errors I did this/ sudo cpan followed by install::slurp

Comment: Was the installation successful? Does `File/Slurp.pm` exist in any of the directories listed in @INC? Also, `install::slurp` is an invalid command, please try to show the exact commands and messages, otherwise there is no way anyone can help you.

Comment: Ya installation was successful. Now there is no error as the previous now it is only saying syntax errors in File::find. I did Install::Slurp it installed all dependencies.

Comment: Where does `File::find` come from? What errors are being reported for it? My crystal ball does not tell me.

Comment: where does File::FIND comes from ????? I did not get u what do you mean by where does it come from!!!!!

Comment: Unquoted string "name" may clash with future reserved word at sample2.pl line 15.
Unquoted string "name" may clash with future reserved word at sample2.pl line 15.
syntax error at sample2.pl line 13, near "File::Find:"
Execution of sample2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: It is `File::Find`. Not `File::find`, nor `File::FIND`. Note the difference. I have no access to `sample2.pl`, so I cannot tell you more.

Comment: Now I am able to remove all the errors and I also got the output and not able to paste my code here and How can I paste my code here!!!!!Help me regarding this!!!!

Comment: Code should be pasted into the main question. Just click `edit`, paste the code, select it, click on `{}`, and `Save Edits`.

Comment: I have pasted my code

Comment: @prashanth: Check the update.

Comment: I am not able to print anything. Means I am not getting any output.

Comment: I wanted to get the line number where exactly the pattern is and how many times it has occured

Comment: @prashanth: Can you show a sample of the data that should match?

Comment: The output should look like this "The pattern clk is found in /home/prodigydell3/verilog/*.v the line number is ? and total no.of instances of pattern clk is ?"

Comment: @prashanth: Can you show a *sample of the data* that should match?

Comment: any updates on this sample of data which I shared with you?

Comment: @prashanth: I see the code, no data.

Comment: Please tell me what is the sample of data you are looking for?

Comment: @prashanth: Just several lines of the verilog file containing the string you are searching for.